# "exit" button is redirecting to wrong page

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm working in online Environment and I have a problem with the exit button on a new form. They redirect to a different start page than the one it should.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Sorty, but it is not clear what you mean with the "Exit" button, what button is this?

Comment: I have a site where you can insert new data into a list. At the bottom I have 2 options, save or exit. I'm trying to take over from someone else, I didn't create this site and I don't know where I can find settings for all functions. I don't have access to Visual Studio at the moment.

Comment: OK, so the "Exit" button will take you to the address that is visible in the url as the "Source=" parameter.

Comment: Yes, but to a different url, that is the problem. This site's url is "something-public.SharePoint.com" and exit will take me to "something.SharePoint.com/network_layouts..."

Comment: How is the edit/new form opened? Seems something goes wrong with the URL there

Comment: I see what you mean, It is actually opened in a new tab with url "something.SharePoint.com/network/_layouts15.." So I guess it is redirected to the networks list and that is on the other site. Do you have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

edit that form in designer and change link on exit button. just put whatever link you want (exp. Home page or something like that)